# iOS dylib symbols not showing up

Tags: ios, dylib

Trying to solve a bug which is crashing the iPad app, I know its coming from my private dylib build for iOS, the crash report stack trace does not show the symbols, the dylib is build for debug for testing.

1. I tried to manually run `symbolicatecrash -A -v "the crash log " "my dylib.dSYM"` does not help.
2. I used `nm` command, it does show my methods.
3. `dwarfdump --lookup "the address" --arch armv7 "path to dSYM"` and it comes back with

   ```
   .debug_info.... not found 
   .debug_frame... not found
   ```

Any ideas how I could get symbols show up for dylib which is packaged as part of the app bundle and will be loaded by app at link time?

Answer (score 0):

Try [otool](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/otool/) to list symbols exported by your dylib:

```
otool -TV your.dylib
```